# Jquery изменить paginator в laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

Делаю ajax запрос при вводе символов. Возвращаю строку в виде html и вставляю в таблицу. Однако ссылки paginatora остаются старые и получается что таблица отфильтрована, но старый пагинатор позволяет пролистывать страницы из первоначальной таблицы. Как изменить ссылки пагинатора?
Код запроса js:

```
$('#id_card').on('keyup', function(){ // поиск
            value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/home',
                data: {
                    search: value,
                    code: 1,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var tab= $('#table_list').find('tbody');
                    tab.empty();
                    tab.append(data);                       
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        })
```

Код контроллера

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $models= Model::where('table','LIKE','%'.$request->input('search').'%')->paginate(4);
    $str = "";
    foreach($models as $model){
        $str .= '<tr>'.
                '<td>'. $model["id"].'</td>'.
                '<td> two</td>'.
                '<td> three</td>'.
                '<td> four</td>'.
                '<td> five</td>'.
                '<td> six</td>'.
                '</tr>';
    }
    print($str);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При Ajax запросе через JQuery ты не передаешь параметр, отвечающий за номер страницы. Ок. Но когда у тебя Ajax возвращает результат в виде HTML кода, который ты вставляешь в тело страницы, то при нажатии на ссылку или что у тебя там, ты должен повторно вызывать этот же AJAX метод, но уже передавать в него номер страницы, на которую нажал на пагинаторе.

Ниже один из вариантов. Вариантов решения данной задачи моет быть очень много, привожу один из вариантов:

**ВАЖНО!** Накидал "на коленке", не проверял код, но принцип показал, надеюсь понятно )

```
// Твой подход при первичной отправке не буду трогать
$('#id_card').on('keyup', function() {
    // поиск
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/home',
        data: {
            search: value,
            code: 1,
            _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var tab= $('#table_list').find('tbody');
                tab.empty();
                tab.append(data.body);

            // Вставляешь содержимое пагинации в блок
            $('#paginator').html(data.paginator);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});

// Пагинация
$(document).on('click', '[data-type="paginator"]', function() {
    // поиск
    // Необходимо указать с какого объекта будет брать строку для поиска
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/home',
        data: {
            search: value,
            code: 1,
            _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
            page: $(this).attr('data-page')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var tab= $('#table_list').find('tbody');
                tab.empty();
                tab.append(data.body);

            // Вставляешь содержимое пагинации в блок
            $('#paginator').html(data.paginator);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Код контроллера

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $models = Model::where('field', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')->paginate(4);
    $str = '';
    foreach($models as $model) {
        $str .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $model->id . '</td>
                <td> two</td>
                <td> three</td>
                <td> four</td>
                <td> five</td>
                <td> six</td>
            </tr>';
    }

    $paginator = '';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $models->lastPage(); $i++) {
        $paginator .= '<a href="javascript:;" data-type="paginator" data-page="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
    }
    echo json_encode(['body' => $str, 'paginator' => $paginator]);

    // Правильнее возвращать сгенерированный текст из функции, а не в ней делать вывод текста
    return;
}
```

### В HTML шаблон добавь блок

```
<div id="paginator"></div>
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо иметь перед глазами пример)
Я просто пробовал вернуть одновременно и html код и ссылку, но там появились проблемы)

Comment: Пара вопросов по контроллеру. 1) Передаете номер страницы, но нигде его не используете. 2) Не до конца понял как вы собираете пагинатор в цикле. Если можно поподробнее.

Comment: 1) Ответ по получению страницы в контролере и установке страницы есть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747801/laravel-5-1-specifing-current-page-for-pagination

Comment: 2) Пагинатор в цикле - это просто перебор всего количества страниц согласно условию запроса. Соответственно мы получаем то количество страниц, которое у нас выбралось по запросу.

Comment: Я бы не слал делать генерацию пагинатора на стороне сервера, если ты передаешь это с помощью AJAX. Наверняка лучше способ просто сделать дополнительные условия по выбборке и ограничению выдачи в модели. Типа ->limit(4)->orderBy(field)->get(); И получать нужное содержимое на страницу.

Comment: А вторым параметром или циклом передавать HTML с пагинацией. Или еще лучше. если ты генерировать пагинацию будешь в самом JS, получать от сервера необходимые параметры в виде количества страниц и текущей страницы и перегенерировать при нажатии. будет динамически быстрее и красивее работать ) А уже сами запросы на получение контента таблицы будет на сервере генерироваться. Хотя с таким же успехом можешь передавать в JS от сервера объект данных и генерировать его динамически.. Вот я тебе целый JS фреймворк тут придумал )